# Relational Database: Variable Fields

Tags: mysql, sql, database, laravel, relational

I am making this hotel reservation program and i'm in a dilemma.

I have the users table that is basically

```
id
identifier
password
realName
cellphone
email
```

The rooms table

```
id
type
price
```

And the reservations table

```
id
checkin
checkout
room_id
nights
total_cost
```

The problem is that a single user in a single reservation can ask for multiple rooms with multiple check ins and outs.

What would be the best approach to achieve this? I was thinking of splitting the various rooms with different reservation ids and then make some kind of workaround to relation them.

Comment: How is users table related to reservation table? Shouldn't be there user_id field?

Comment: Sorry i missed that. Look for the picture that i posted on Gordon Linoff's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your data structure is fine as far as it goes.  You have two choices.

The first is to relax your language.  Don't say that "a single user in a single reservation can ask for multiple rooms with multiple check ins and outs".  Instead say, "a single user can make multiple reservations at the same time".  Just changing this language fixes your conundrum.

If you really have to tie things together, I might suggest having an column that groups reservations made by a single user together.  This could be a full-blown entity, which would have a foreign key reference to another table.  Or, it could simply be an identifier, such as the first reservation in the series or the user id with a date/time stamp.  I'm not sure that a full blown entity is needed, but you might find it useful.

Comment: I was working on this before your answered and i think it's close to what you suggested. http://puu.sh/aWn7o/f95327c11b.png
I translated the important parts(i'm native spanish speaker). What about this solution?

Comment: @Mercality . . . That looks fine.  That is the alternative "full blown entity" approach.  The extra indirection from reservations through requests to users should be fine for your application.